# Why file read is faster on reading again?

Tags: python, linux, file

```
SIZE = 1<<16
def justread(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        while f.read(SIZE):
            pass
```

The first time I run this function on a 700MB file it took 19 secs.
When I repeated
reading the same file again the time it took dropped to 0.5secs.
I repeated this with many files and the results were similar.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The operating system [caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) the file in memory upon the first read, and the second time it is read from memory instead of from hard disk.  Of course memory is much faster.

Comment: If its stored in ram, why is it not showing up in memory usage.

Comment: @simha use "free" command at linux. It will show you memory used by cache

Comment: Just asking... Is there a way we can tell the system to cache a file before we read it?.....

Comment: @simha: The easiest way to do this is to read it once without saving the result.

Comment: @simha: the memory isn't used by any specific process; the kernel just keeps stuff there until it needs the memory for something "more important".

Answer (score 5):

Your operating system is caching the file.

**What?** This means, the first time you read the file, your program had to go look for the information in the hard drive, and hard drives are slooooow.

Now, after having read the whole file for the first time, Linux kept it around in memory just in case, and probably because there was nothing important to have instead at the time. So, the second time you read it, you were accessing the copy in memory, without reaching for the hard drive, which is orders of magnitude faster.

Cheers!