# Efficient load of 2D/4D masked array with h5py

Tags: python, arrays, performance, h5py

I have data stored in large 4-D arrays in HDF5 files. The dimensions of each file are (Time,x,y,z). I would like to load a subset of the Time columns, with *some* of the x,y,z values, to get a 2D (T,location) matrix. I have a 3D logical mask for all the x,y,z locations I want to load. My question is: am I better off re-formatting my stored data to be 2D?

I thought the answer would be an easy "Yes", since hdf5 masking syntax allows you to use logical arrays as masks for a single dimension but not multiple dimensions. Code example:

MyTestScript.py

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
# Shape of 'data' variable in h is (900,50,150,150)
sz = (50,150,150)
h = h5py.File('DataStore.hf5')
# Keep 1000 random values
mask = np.hstack((ones(1000),zeros(prod(sz)-1000)))
np.random.shuffle(mask)
mask = mask.reshape(sz)

# 4D array:
masked_data = h['data'].value[:,mask]
# if 'data' were a 2D array instead (900 x 1125000):
masked_data = h['data'][:,mask.flatten()]
```

Based on my current understanding of h5py, the second option listed (if 'data' were a 2D array) seems as if it should load much faster, since it's never loading the entire array. And in first-pass tests of code similar to the above, it does go substantially faster (~10x faster - I had timing checks in the real script).

However, the time difference almost entirely goes away after the first run-through of the code. BOTH versions now load much faster, as if the hdf5 file (or the interpreter for the code?) has somehow cached the fully-loaded data. I don't see how it's doing that, since I'm doing it in separate python sessions each time (python MyTestScript.py).

What's going on? What is the source of the speed-up? When can I count on it happening?

THANKS for any insights.

Comment: Your OS is [caching](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4449491/190597) the contents of the file in RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm currently on ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal); is this uniquely a linux thing? Do other OSs do this as well?

Comment: It is a standard feature of all modern OSs. There is some ways to configure the behavior on Linux (e.g. [swappiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness)), so I would expect all OSs implement it a bit differently, however.

Comment: Thanks! P.S. know what you call a cow that just gave birth? de-calf-inated. =-)

Comment: Haha! can I add that to my profile? :)

Comment: Go ahead =-) also, pardon the duplication; was confused as to whether the speed-up had anything to do with mysterious behavior of h5py